Split string on boundaries in Rust
Is there a nice (ideally built in or in itertools) way to split a &str on boundaries? For example I want to split where c.is_alphanumeric() or c.is_whitespace() changes.
My current solution is to use chunk_by(), however it only works on slices, not &str, so I have to convert back to a &str.
for text in x
    .as_bytes()
    .chunk_by(|c0, c1| c0.is_ascii_alphanumeric() == c1.is_ascii_alphanumeric())
{
    let text = std::str::from_utf8(text).unwrap();

I believe the unwrap() is safe in this instance, but it feels a bit icky and it means I'm operating on bytes instead of chars.
Basically is there chunk_by for &str?

str::split or one of it's varaints? The pattern can be a function.

I believe split operates on individual characters though. You can't tell from looking at one character if it is a boundary or not - you need to look at adjacent characters like chunk_by allows.

Your closure can remember the previous character.

Ah true. But it still won't work because split removes all of the splitting characters. I don't want any characters removed.

Ah there's split_inclusive; let me try...

Just realized split_inclusive will probably always split one character late. So it probably won't work.

Yeah you're right - it did exactly that. I'll just write my own chunk_by for str.

Here is an implementation of a string chunker (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9755e0a0863b0559695446eedab60f41):
struct StringChunker<'a, F> {
    s: &'a str,
    index: usize, // byte index
    predicate: F,
    prev: bool,
}

impl<'a, F> StringChunker<'a, F> {
    fn new(s: &'a str, predicate: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            s,
            index: 0,
            predicate,
            prev: false,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, F: Fn(char) -> bool> Iterator for StringChunker<'a, F> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let Self {
            s,
            index,
            prev,
            predicate,
        } = self;

        if *index >= s.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let mut j = *index;
        while j < s.len() {
            let curr_char = s[j..].chars().next().unwrap();
            let pred = predicate(curr_char);

            if pred != *prev && j > 0 {
                *prev = pred;
                break;
            }

            *prev = pred;
            j += curr_char.len_utf8();
        }

        let ret = Some(&s[*index..j]);
        *index = j;
        ret
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test_cases = [
        ("", [].as_slice()),
        (" ", [" "].as_slice()),
        ("  ", ["  "].as_slice()),
        ("   ", ["   "].as_slice()),
        ("a", ["a"].as_slice()),
        ("ab", ["ab"].as_slice()),
        ("abc", ["abc"].as_slice()),
        (" a", [" ", "a"].as_slice()),
        ("a ", ["a", " "].as_slice()),
        (" a ", [" ", "a", " "].as_slice()),
        ("a b", ["a", " ", "b"].as_slice()),
        (" a   b", [" ", "a", "   ", "b"].as_slice()),
        ("a   b  ", ["a", "   ", "b", "  "].as_slice()),
        (" a   b cd", [" ", "a", "   ", "b", " ", "cd"].as_slice()),
        (
            " a   b cd ",
            [" ", "a", "   ", "b", " ", "cd", " "].as_slice(),
        ),
    ];
    for (input, expected) in test_cases {
        assert_eq!(
            expected,
            StringChunker::new(input, char::is_whitespace).collect::<Vec<_>>()
        );
        assert_eq!(
            expected,
            StringChunker::new(input, |c| !char::is_whitespace(c))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        );
    }
}


Lifetimes, generics with Fn, structs with Iterator implementation, struct  destructuring, the intricacies of UTF-8 chars.
This might seriously be the most packed answer I have seen, a true delight for a beginner as I. Thanks for sharing!

You shouldn't put the Fn bounds on the struct or in new. See this question for details.

@FilipeRodrigues Right you are. Fixed

Here's the implementation I went for which is basically a copy/paste of slice::chunk_by, and matches its API, so you can do a_str.chunk_by(|l, r| l.is_whitespace() == r.is_whitespace()), exactly the same as for slices.
Thanks @
use std::{fmt, iter::FusedIterator};

pub trait StrChunkBy {
    fn chunk_by<F>(&self, pred: F) -> ChunkBy<'_, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(char, char) -> bool;
}

impl StrChunkBy for &str {
    #[inline]
    fn chunk_by<F>(&self, pred: F) -> ChunkBy<'_, F>
    where
        F: FnMut(char, char) -> bool,
    {
        ChunkBy::new(self, pred)
    }
}

/// An iterator over str chunks separated by a predicate.
///
/// This struct is created by the [`chunk_by`] method on [str].
///
/// [`chunk_by`]: str::chunk_by
#[must_use = "iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed"]
pub struct ChunkBy<'a, P> {
    string: &'a str,
    predicate: P,
}

impl<'a, P> ChunkBy<'a, P> {
    pub(super) fn new(string: &'a str, predicate: P) -> Self {
        ChunkBy { string, predicate }
    }
}

impl<'a, P> Iterator for ChunkBy<'a, P>
where
    P: FnMut(char, char) -> bool,
{
    type Item = &'a str;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.string.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let mut len = None;
            let mut left_char = None;
            for (right_index, right_char) in self.string.char_indices() {
                if let Some(left_char) = left_char {
                    if !(self.predicate)(left_char, right_char) {
                        len = Some(right_index);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                left_char = Some(right_char);
            }
            let (head, tail) = self.string.split_at(len.unwrap_or(self.string.len()));
            self.string = tail;
            Some(head)
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        if self.string.is_empty() {
            (0, Some(0))
        } else {
            (1, Some(self.string.len()))
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, P> FusedIterator for ChunkBy<'a, P> where P: FnMut(char, char) -> bool {}

impl<'a, P> fmt::Debug for ChunkBy<'a, P> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("ChunkBy")
            .field("string", &self.string)
            .finish()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_str_chunk_by() {
        let test_cases = [
            ("", [].as_slice()),
            (" ", [" "].as_slice()),
            ("  ", ["  "].as_slice()),
            ("   ", ["   "].as_slice()),
            ("a", ["a"].as_slice()),
            ("ab", ["ab"].as_slice()),
            ("abc", ["abc"].as_slice()),
            (" a", [" ", "a"].as_slice()),
            ("a ", ["a", " "].as_slice()),
            (" a ", [" ", "a", " "].as_slice()),
            ("a b", ["a", " ", "b"].as_slice()),
            (" a   b", [" ", "a", "   ", "b"].as_slice()),
            ("a   b  ", ["a", "   ", "b", "  "].as_slice()),
            (" a   b cd", [" ", "a", "   ", "b", " ", "cd"].as_slice()),
            (
                " a   b cd ",
                [" ", "a", "   ", "b", " ", "cd", " "].as_slice(),
            ),
        ];
        for (input, expected) in test_cases {
            assert_eq!(
                expected,
                input
                    .chunk_by(|l, r| l.is_whitespace() == r.is_whitespace())
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            );
        }
    }
}

